# How to get DL in Exchange Server using Java API?

Tags: java, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

How to get DL (distribution List) from Microsoft Exchange Server via EWS in Java?

I have tried [EWS Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) but could not find list of `Distribution List`(GAL) of exchange server, any help regarding to this API or any other would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GAL is not directly supported. You can use the ResolveNames method to resolve individual names. To perform a search on the GAL, you need to use LDAP. See http://www.infinitec.de/post/2005/02/How-to-get-the-Global-Address-List-programatically.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on JIntegra. I remember that they support of MS Exchange. Probably some API exists. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LDAP if you have access to that. Or PowerShell. But Henning is right EWS itself has pretty limited stuff here.