# Getting the list of distribution lists using ewp api in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get all distribution lists & the members of those lists using the ewp api in c#.
I made the connection to the outlook server and I can get the calendar information of mine using c#. But I couldn't find a way to get the distribution lists.

Comment: Although in java [How to get DL in EWS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926347/how-to-get-dl-in-exchange-server-using-java-api) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that we can't get the distribution lists. Because distribution lists are not stored in the exchange server. They are a separate concept and have to use some other method to get the lists.